# How to format a NSDate in dd/MM/YYYY

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsdate

I'm trying to get an NSDate into the format: **20/05/2014 22:30**

here's the code I currently have. 
    `[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"];`
 this works but the format is not like **20/05/2014 22:30** it displays the date in format like: 12-03-2013 12:00:00 +00:00:00

and then when I use:

`[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];` I get a `null` value returned instead of a formatted date.

```
// timestamp conversion
    NSString *str = [timeStamp objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    // convert to date
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
  //  [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"];

 [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];

    NSDate *dte = [dateFormat dateFromString:str];
    cell.timeStampLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",dte ];
```

the str original string output before formatting is `str 2013-08-23T15:21:19+02:00`

thanks for any help

Comment: you are currently set nsdate to label so it will be like 12-03-2013 12:00:00 +00:00:00

Comment: http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Comment: Without having any idea about str date format it's hard to convert it to date. give us an example of possible value for str.

Comment: did you try ? got your answer or not?

Comment: It's hard to post a useful answer (for proof just look at the guessing that is going on here) for this question. You don't tell us which NSString you want to convert into a NSDate.

Comment: The first thing to do is to read the spec for [NSDateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html).  The second thing to do is to consult the (somewhat hard to locate) spec for the [date patterns](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns).  When you do that you will see that you should use "yyyy", not "YYYY".

Comment: The third thing to do is to understand that the date format describes (duh!!) *the intended format of the date*!!!

Comment: (Quit simply copying code off the net and try to UNDERSTAND what you are doing!)

Comment: (And, by the way, an NSDate contains no format information -- when you log it it is always logged the same way.  You use a date format to convert an NSDate to/from a displayable string.)

Comment: the str original string output before formatting is `str 2013-08-23T15:21:19+02:00`

Answer (score 37, accepted):

you have to do like this but please first of check your str's date format

```
NSString *str = [timeStamp objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"];


NSDate *dte = [dateFormat dateFromString:str];

[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"];
cell.timeStampLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dateFormat stringFromDate:dte]];
```

first time set date format same as in your str.

Comment: Also consider setting the `locale` as suggested in [Apple Technical Q&A 1480](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1480/_index.html).

Answer (score 3):

First set the `NSDateFormatter` to the format you are receiving data to retain it into a NSDate Object and then again use your desired format to change it into the format you want and show it. For more you can see **Pratik** answer.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

I think that enforcing the locale` and its appearance programatically is a bad idea unless it is has been specified as a requirement.

An alternative would be to use `setDateStyle` on the `NSDateFormatter`, to one of the formats specified under `System Preferences -> Language & Text -> Region -> Dates`.
There is a Short , Medium and a Long format to choose from for both Time and Date.
Available styles are listed in the documentation under [NSDateFormatterStyle](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSDateFormatterStyle)

Now to answer your question:
If you would append the *short time* format to the *medium date* format then you would get your desired outcome, while maintaining both localizability and customisability.

Answer (score 3):

set your date formate in [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"]; so that u code write in way

```
// timestamp conversion
NSString *str = [timeStamp objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
// convert to date
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
//  [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"];

[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"];

NSDate *dte = [dateFormat dateFromString:str];
cell.timeStampLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",dte ];
```

I hope it is helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Just use below code and you will get the result:

// timestamp conversion

```
NSString *str = [timeStamp objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

// convert to date

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd T HH:mm:ss ZZZZ"];

NSDate *dte = [dateFormat dateFromString:str];

[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"];

cell.timeStampLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dateFormat stringFromDate:dte]];
```

Comment: thanks, I tried that but I get a null value for the formatted date. my original str value is: str 2013-08-23T15:21:19+02:00

Comment: I have edited my answer according to your input string. Please check.

Answer (score 1):

Set Your date formatter to

```
 [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"];
```

// timestamp conversion

```
NSString *str = [timeStamp objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"];

NSDate *dte = [dateFormat dateFromString:str];
cell.timeStampLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",dte ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at DateFormatters to use required formats:
[Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html)

Answer (score 0):

**NSString *strNotificationTimeAndDate="Your date";

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.z"];
```

or

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss+z"];
```

or

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssz"];
```

or

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z"];
NSDate *commentdate = [dateFormat 
dateFromString:strNotificationTimeAndDate];**
```